# List in session is always showing empty - flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Ok, so let me say I have a "shopping list"

I need this shopping list to be unique for every person that visits the flask app.

So I plan to store the list in session.

So I planned to set the list session['list'] = [] using the @app.before_first_request

However whenever I append to the session list, I end up with an empty list.
Why? I append like this:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/?add=4

I would like to see a string of all the list items on the index route and be able to append new items to the list if there is a "add" query.

However, this code just appends one thing to the list and then it goes back to being empty.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, url_for, redirect, session, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisisasecret!'



@app.before_first_request
def init_app():

   session['list'] = []
    
   return



@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():

    add = request.args.get("add")
    
    if add:
        session['list'].append(add)
        
    return str(session['list'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the `append` method of `session['list']` behaves like that.  I see multiple hits to `/?add=randomValue` eventually keep modifying the second list item, rather creating a third, and so-forth.

Using a variable `l` to temporarily store the full list, then writing it back to `session['list']`, seems to give the behaviour you were hoping for:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    add = request.args.get("add")
    l = session['list']

    if add:
        l.append(add)
    
    session['list'] = l
    return str(l)
```

Also: Perhaps rather than the `before_first_request` which runs once for the **application instance** (so when a second user connects with a different browser, that code won't run a second time) you probably want `before_request` with some logic to see if the `list` key exists in `session`:

```
# Runs before every request!
@app.before_request
def before_req():
   if 'list' not in session:
       session['list'] = []
    
   return
```

Although this may answer your question, I'm not sure if this is the best approach for implementing a shopping cart system in 2020, unless it's just for learning reasons of course! :-)